# Instigating CSS animation with Javascript

Tags: javascript, css, animation

I currently have it so my titles slide in when the link is clicked.
How do I make it so that (when the link is clicked) the current title will slide out before the new one slides in?

This is the clicked event I have been using. It might be all wonky, I have been adding different things to it to try and get it to work.

```
// list of sections.  the first section contains only the h1.
var sections = document.querySelectorAll("section");

function hideSections() {
  for (var i = 0; i < sections.length; i++) {
    sections[i].className = "hidden";
  }
}

// list of links in the nav.
var links = document.querySelector("nav").querySelectorAll("a");

// add listeners to those links
for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
  links[i].addEventListener("click", clicked);
}

function clicked(event) {
  var target = document.querySelector('h2');
  target.className = "slideout";

  event.preventDefault();
  hideSections();

  var current = event.target.hash;
  // "show" appropriate selection, based on id from link
  document.querySelector(current).className = "";

  // modify URL to reflect current location
  location.hash = current;

  target.addEventListener("animationend", newfile);

  function newfile() {
    target.removeEventListener("animationend", newfile);
  }
  target.addEventListener("animationstart", newfile);

}

// when page loads...
hideSections();

if (location.hash == "") {
  sections[0].className = "";
} else {
  document.querySelector(location.hash).className = "";
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/yk7w2zt2/
Here is my full code.

Comment: When you are seeing the click you are hiding the title and content you don't want, and since you are doing this with display: none there is no animation.

Answer (score 0):

You need you delay showing the next section until after the h2 has slid off the screen. 
See JSFiddle using `setTimeout()`:

https://jsfiddle.net/w9uypaae/